# Vertical line appearing in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I open the terminal in VS code, a vertical line is appearing in that terminal. How can I get rid of this line?

[image: Picture of Line in Editor]

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with windows.maybe switch powershell to other shell?

Comment: Hmmmm... Have you tried changing the theme?

Comment: No, It's problem of terminal height.

Comment: No, it's a terminal line height. I changed the setting of this in vs code settings and set integrated terminal line height value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

[image: settings in vs code terminal]

I found the solution to this problem, actually it's a vs code terminal line height, now I set it's height to default.